# Create custom Perma link

Tags: categories, permalinks

I have a page with with address localhost/ .
.In the navigation bar  I have a new page link named Blog. SO wheni travel to that page the link is localhost/blog .
 Now here is my thing ...when i click on any post of that page the next page permalink become
localhost/{The-post-name}.
what i want is to print the link fully...
like /localhost/blog/{the-post-name}. for every post i walk through this page

Answer (score 0):

Just go to *Settings > Permalinks*, select *Custom Structure* and enter the following:

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

That will add `/blog/` to the beginning of post names in their permalinks. This will not affect Pages.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a rewrite rule to WordPress:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_328813_rewrite' );
function wpse_328813_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^blog/(.+)/?$', 
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

What that is saying is, "WordPress, when someone requests a URL with "blog", followed by a slash, and then some text, maybe followed by another slash, try to load a page matching that slug. Oh, and do this before you try any of your other rewrite rules."

Comment: Massive overkill. You can achieve the same thing for posts just by changing the settings in *Settings > Permalinks*.

Comment: We must have different understandings of the word, "massive". A custom permalink structure in the menu does make more sense for what he said. I just jump to rewrite rules because they are more flexible, and invariably the person will come back with, "Oh, well what I really meant was only if..."